# Why inject into themself

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to make jira plugin and can't understand why class inject constructor in themself

```java
@JiraComponent
public class IssueKeyValidator {
    @Inject
    public IssueKeyValidator(IssueManager issueManager) {
        this.issueManager = issueManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: that class won't compile. there is no instance variable with name issueManager, so this.issueManager won't work. Just check this link: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/creating-a-custom-mail-handler-for-jira/

Comment: What do you mean by "in themself"? One's `IssueKeyValidator`, and it requires the `IssueManager`.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I think he means in the same (local) variable. He forgot to add the instance variable issueManager.

Comment: @Stultuske, it can't be local since it has the `this.` before it.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov which is why I stated in my first comment that it won't compile. But either he's not showing his actual code, or in his case, that's exact the error message he gets. Sure, it has the this keyword, but do you see an instance variable of that type/name there? It also doesn't seem to extend a parent class, so it 's not inherited either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Inject` annotiation on the constructor level does not mean that the constructors class is injected but instances of the classes in the parameters of the constructor.
In this case the `@Inject` says that an `IssueManager` bean should be injected into `IssueKeyValidator`s constructor.

> `public @interface Inject`
>
> Identifies injectable constructors, methods, and fields. May apply to static as well as instance members. An injectable member may have any access modifier (private, package-private, protected, public). Constructors are injected first, followed by fields, and then methods. Fields and methods in superclasses are injected before those in subclasses. Ordering of injection among fields and among methods in the same class is not specified.
>
> Injectable constructors are annotated with @Inject and accept zero or more dependencies as arguments. @Inject can apply to at most one constructor per class.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html